# MySql JSONObject Ifnull

Tags: mysql

I am working on Mysql query to retrieve the JSON Object

`Select JSON_OBJECT('id', students.id, 'name', students.name) as test from students;`

output

```
         "test": {
            "id": null,
            "name": null
          }
```

expected output

`test: null`

How can i check if test object has a null values then return null

Comment: Your "expected output" is not valid JSON. From the looking point of MySQL at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i check if test object has a null values then return null

Formally (without understanding the logic):

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN students.id IS NULL AND students.name IS NULL
            THEN CAST( 'null' AS JSON )
            ELSE JSON_OBJECT('id', students.id, 'name', students.name) 
            END AS test 
FROM students;
```